# C++ - initializing static member its own method

Tags: c++, oop, methods, static, initialization

Is it possible to initialize static member with its own method eg. initialize()?

Example:

```
class Foo
{
//some private variables
public:
static Bar example;
//some methods
}
```

Then call it in main.cpp like:

```
Foo::example.initialize(argument);
```

Of course it does not work. Also it has lack in encapsulation because variable is public. I woud like it to be private and initialized just once. I do not have any other option than initializing it with a method.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What outcome did you expect, and what did you observe instead? On the face of it, I don't see a reason why it would be a problem. If you want to make `example` private, define a static method on `Foo` that would turn around and call `example.initialize()`

Comment: I get "undefined reference to `Foo::example'" in main.cpp.

Comment: That's a separate problem. You have only declared `example` - you also need to define it. In some .cpp (not .h) file, write `Bar Foo::example;`

Comment: Oh, that's why it didn't work. Also static method tip was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: imho encapsulation and public are orthogonal, but I know I have some crude views concerning encapsulation ;)

Answer (score 1):

The default way for initializing an object should be by it's default construtor.

If it is really needed then a Singleton can be used (be aware it is an Anti-pattern: [What is an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980601/what-is-an-anti-pattern#980616) , also [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons))

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static const Bar& getBarInstance()
    {
        static Bar bar;

        return bar;
    }
};
```

This will only be initialized once.