# Making a list from data in a few variable bash script

Tags: bash, list

Hello I have a few variables with information, for example:

```
$names=

Tomer      
Jacob      
Adam 

$Age:
25 
27 
28

$Country:
USA
Spain
Brazil
```

I would like to merge and print  these details in a form that each lines presents a person with all his details
Wanted OUPUT:

Tomer      25      USA

Jacob      27      Spain

Adam       28      Brazil

i have tried to do something like this

```
for i in {1..$NumberOfLines} 
do 
echo $Names | head -$((i))
echo $Ages | head -$((i))
echo $Country | head -$((i))
done
```

of ocurse its not working

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `paste` command in some form or another, but your exposition is rather unclear. If the text is in variables, Bash lets you do something like `paste <(echo "$Names") <(echo "$Ages") <(echo "$Country")` but this seems quite unnatural; usually it would be more convenient if these values came from files.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this

Comment: Please write syntactically correct assignment statements for your variables. If you just sketch the content, I don't even know whether you are using scalars or arrays to hold this information.