# Linux - Delete all lines from a given line number

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sed

I am trying to delete a file's contents from a supplied line number using sed. The problem is that sed isn't accepting the variable I supply to it

```
line_num=$(grep -n "debited" file.csv | sed -n '2 s/:.*//p') && sed -i.bak "$line_num,$d" file.csv
```

The idea is to delete all lines from a file after & including the second occurence of the pattern.

I'm not stubborn with `sed`. `Awk` & `perl` could do too.

Comment: Your shell is probably interpolating the `$d`. Try putting a backslash in front of the `$d`.

Comment: Looks to me that the "given" part here is the word "debited", not a line number.

Comment: Why not use `head`?

Comment: See also [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)

Comment: Any time you find yourself using multiple pipes between grep and sed you should be using awk instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always suggest `ed` for **ed**iting files over trying to use `sed` to do it; a program intended from the beginning to work with a file instead of a stream of lines just works better for most tasks.

> The idea is to delete all lines from a file after & including the second occurence[sic] of the pattern

Example:

```
$ cat demo.txt
a
b
c
debited 12
d
e
debited 14
f
g
h
$ printf "%s\n" '/debited/;//,$d' w | ed -s demo.txt
$ cat demo.txt
a
b
c
debited 12
d
e
```

The `ed` command `/pattern/;//,$d` first sets the current line cursor to the first one that matches the basic regular expression *pattern*, then moves it to the next match of the pattern and deletes everything from there to the end of the file. Then `w` writes the changed file back to disk.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. Choosing your solution over the other brilliant ones as it edits the file in place & is faster to run.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you want to delete the rest of the file after a second showing of a pattern (`debited`), including that line.

Then can [truncate](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate) it, ising [tell](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell) for the length of what's been read up to that line

```
perl -e'while (<>) { 
    if ( ($cnt += /debited/) == 2 ) { truncate $ARGV, $len; exit } 
    $len = tell;
}' file
```

Here the [$ARGV variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$ARGV) has the "current" file (when reading from [<>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators)). Feel free to introduce a variable with the pattern instead of the literal (`debited`), based on your context.

This can be made to look far nicer in a little script but it seems that a command-line program ("one-liner") is needed in the question.

Comment: You could just `close ARGV`... `perl -pi.bak -e'if ( ($c += /debited/) == 2 ) { close ARGV }' file`. As I recall, it works even with multiple files. Untested.

Comment: @TLP Yeah, a good idea -- I'd think that it absolutely should truncate it -- but it doesn't? Maybe my testing's faulty somehow...

Comment: @TLP oh ... actually, can't do that: once the line with the second `debited` _has been_ read it's too late to simply truncate where we are (even if it worked); it has to truncate to the length of up to that line, and can't accomplish that using `close ARGV`. A good idea, regardless

Comment: The perldoc says that it can depend on your system. Oh right, yes, you have to print *after* the check, and use `-n`.

Answer (score 2):

you're doing lot's of unnecessary steps, this will do what you want.

```
$ awk '/debited/{c++} c==2{exit}1' file
```

delete second occurrence of the pattern and everything after it.

To replace the original file (and create backup)

```
$ awk ... file > t && mv -b --suffix=.bak t file
```