# Splitting a file based on tags - grep, sed?

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that consists of tags and content descriptions, e.g.:

```
@ABC-1111 @ANYTAG
Content: description
content1
content2
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2
@ABC-0000
Content: anything here
content1
content2
```

I would like to split this file based on the tags it contains with a certain prefix (e.g "ABC") along with its content below it. So from the example file above, it will be split into 3 files (since there are 3 tags with "ABC" prefix).

File "ABC-0000" (found 3 instances in the file):

```
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2
@ABC-0000
Content: anything here
content1
content2
```

File "ABC-1111" (found two instances in the file):

```
@ABC-1111 @ANYTAG
Content: description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2
```

File "ABC-2222" (found 1 instance in the file):

```
@ABC-2222 @ABC-1010 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
```

I was trying to use bash script with sed:

```
  for i in $(grep -Eo ‘@ABC-[0-9]+’ $file | sort -u); do
    sed -n -r "/${i}/,/^\s*$/p" $file >> $i.out
  done
```

seems it works only if there is a blank line between the content of the tag with the next tag line.

Is there a way to do this with grep, sed, or awk? Or maybe in python?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, Thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: Your problem statement isn't very clear, but this sort of thing is very easy to do in Awk. Regarding your attempt, perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this

Answer (score 3):

You can use csplit to split up the files into sections with their tags:

```
csplit --quiet -f xx ./input.txt '/^@/' '{*}'
TAGS=$(grep -o '@[^ ]*' ./input.txt | sort | uniq)
for TAG in $TAGS
do
  grep -l $TAG xx* | xargs cat > $(echo $TAG | tr -d '@')
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- all tag lines start with a `@` in column #1
- all lines that start with `@` in column #1 are tag lines

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
$1 ~ /^@/ { delete flist                     # delete array of output files
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {            # loop through list of tags
                if ($i ~ "^@ABC-") {         # if tag starts with "@ABC-" then ..
                   flist[substr($i,2)]       # strip off the "@" and save result as name of an output file
                }
            }
          }

          { for (file in flist)              # for each file in our array ...
                print $0 >> file             # append the current line
          }
' tag.dat
```

**NOTES:**

- as currently coded `awk` will maintain an open file descriptor for each tag/file processed
- for a smallish number of tags/files this likely won't be a problem for most `awk` implementations
- if running `GNU awk` you should be able to maintain a sizeable number of open file descriptors
- if receiving a message that `awk` has exceeded the max number of open file descriptors there are a couple ideas that come to mind:

  - before `delete files` run `for (file in flist) close(file)`; this will likely slow down the overall speed of the script due to an excessive number of open/close file operations
  - store each tag's data in memory (there are a few ways to do this) and in `END {...}` processing loop through a master list of tags, performing a single `open/write-all-data-from-memory/close` operation for each tag; assumes the entire file can fit in memory

Results:

```
for f in ABC-*
do
    printf "\n############# $f\n"
    cat $f
done

############# ABC-0000
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2
@ABC-0000
Content: anything here
content1
content2

############# ABC-1111
@ABC-1111 @ANYTAG
Content: description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2

############# ABC-2222
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^@/ { prt(); rec=tags=$0; next }
{ rec=rec ORS $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i,n,t) {
    n = split(tags,t,/ *@/)
    for ( i=2; i<=n; i++ ) {
        print rec > (t[i])
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

```
$ head -50 A*
==> ABC-0000 <==
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2
@ABC-0000
Content: anything here
content1
content2

==> ABC-1111 <==
@ABC-1111 @ANYTAG
Content: description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2

==> ABC-2222 <==
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2

==> ANYTAG <==
@ABC-1111 @ANYTAG
Content: description
content1
content2
@ABC-2222 @ABC-0000 @ANYTAG
Content: another description
content1
content2
@ANYTAG @ABC-1111 @ABC-0000
Content: yet another description
content1
content2
```

The above assumes you either don't have so many output files as to trigger the `too many open files` error or are using an awk version such as GNU awk that can handle arbitrary numbers of simultaneously open files. If that's not the case then change `print rec > (t[i])` to `print rec >> (t[i]); close(t[i])`.