# Bash script to mark inserted date from upper row if date is absent at start of row

Tags: bash, awk

Сontinuation of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623364/bash-script-to-insert-date-from-upper-row-if-date-is-absent-at-start-of-row#comment128289497_72623364)
The log file that I am working with has some rows with or without date at the beginning of row.
I'm able to insert date from upper row if date is absent at start of row.
I need mark existing date with 00000 and with sequence for new inserted date.

I work in MingW64 under Windows 10.
Date is in format: 2022-06-09 17:47:08,371

**Given file:**
date1 string1
(some spaces or tabs)     string2       date (just a date in log, not the date at the beginning of the row; leading spaces)
, string3
date2 string4
string5
]string6
date3 string7
date4 string8
date5 string9

**Expected file:**
date1:0000**0** string1
date1:0000**1** , string2 - increment of mark
date1:0000**2**        string3 date (just a date in log, not the date at the beginning of the row; leading spaces)
date2:0000**0** string4 - new date starts with 00000
date2:0000**1** string5
date2:0000**2** ]string6
date3:0000**0** string7 - new date starts with 00000
date4:0000**0** string8 - new date starts with 00000
date5:0000**0** string9 - new date starts with 00000

**Example of given file:**

```
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000 string1
       string2
string3
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000 string4  
string5
string6
2022-06-09 10:00:03,000:00000 string7
2022-06-09 10:00:04,000:00000 string8
2022-06-09 10:00:05,000:00000 string9
```

**Example of expected file:**

```
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000:00000 string1  
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000:00001        string2
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000:00002 string3  
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000:00000 string4
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000:00001 string5
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000:00002 string6
2022-06-09 10:00:03,000:00000:00000 string7
2022-06-09 10:00:04,000:00000:00000 string8
2022-06-09 10:00:05,000:00000:00000 string9
```

**script that can be used as a template**
from @Walter A

```
awk '
  /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}/ {last_d_t=$1 " " $2; print; next}
 {print last_d_t $0}
' test.txt
```

or
from @Daweo

```
awk '/^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/{d=substr($0, 1, 24);print;next}{print d $0}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I simplified a little bit the regex
It should work as long as your "strings" cannot start with `YYYY-MM-DD`

```bash
awk '
    match($0,/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9:,]+/) {
        n = 0
        prefix = substr($0,1,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,1+RLENGTH)
    }
    { printf("%s:%05d%s%s\n",prefix,n,(n++?" ":""),$0) }
' file
```

```
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000:00000 string1
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000:00001        string2
2022-06-09 10:00:01,000:00000:00002 string3
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000:00000 string4  
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000:00001 string5
2022-06-09 10:00:02,000:00000:00002 string6
2022-06-09 10:00:03,000:00000:00000 string7
2022-06-09 10:00:04,000:00000:00000 string8
2022-06-09 10:00:05,000:00000:00000 string9
```

Comment: Great! Works as expected. Thanks!