# Shell command to print the statements with N number of words present in other file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Suppose I have a file with 3 lines:

`output.txt`:

```
Maruti
Zen
Suzuki
```

I used the command `wc -l output.txt` to get no. of lines
i got output as 3

Based on the above output I have to execute a command

```
echo CREATE FROM (sed -n 1p OUTPUT.txt)
echo CREATE FROM (sed -n 2p OUTPUT.txt)
echo CREATE FROM (sed -n 3p OUTPUT.txt)
:
:
echo CREATE FROM (sed -n np OUTPUT.txt)
```

Can you please suggest a command to replace 1 2 3 .....n in the above command based on the output i get (i.e., no. of lines in my file)

I just gave a sample explanation of my use case. Please suggest a command to execute n no. of times.

Comment: `while read line; do echo "CREATE FROM $line"; done < output.txt`

Comment: Excessive use of ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING on here, just look at the other questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one command.

```
sed 's/^/CREATE FROM /' output.txt
```

See also [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)