# Integrate Error Message in while condition Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to extract from a website multiple files, but I don't want to do this manually.
Instead I want to download these files until there is an error like: `ERROR 404: Not Found.`

For example I have on this website some files called:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
.
.
.
file10.txt
```

and I use `wget http:...`.
If I try to download `file11.txt`, which does not exists, I get the `ERROR 404: Not Found` Error.

If I try to do something like:

```
while [condition]
do
   NR=$((NR+1));
   wget ...
done
```

where `NR` is the variable that will change the number of the file.

What should I use as `condition` to stop the loop when it reaches a file that does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the `wget` call directly in the condition position of the `while` loop, since it works based on the exit code of the command (it will loop as long as the exit code is `0`):

```bash
declare -i counter=1

while wget "http://example.com/file${counter}.txt"; do
  counter+=1
done
```

The `-i` part in `declare -i` makes sure that a few lines below `+=` means arithmetic addition and not string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `break` if `wget` fails.

```
while IFS= read -r url; do
    wget "$url" || break
done <file.txt
```

Your attempt seems to succumb to the antipattern in [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)

The same thing can work if the URLs don't come from a file.

```
for((i=1; ;++i)); do
    wget "http://site.example/file$i.txt" || break
done
```

The "C-style" `for` loop syntax here is a Bash extension, and not portable to regular `sh`.