# replace file context with "/" in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

my sample file is like:

```bash
# sample.txt
adc=lalalala
cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo"
cda=lolololo
```

i wish to replace line of `cmd` like:

```bash
old=`cat ./sample.txt|grep cmd`
app=' && echo dudu"'

new=${old:0:-1}${app}

sed -i "s/${old}/${new}/g" ./sample.txt
```

the expect result should be

```bash
adc=lalalala
cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo && echo dudu"
cda=lolololo
```

however turned out:

```bash
adc=lalalala
cmd="echo hihi cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo"cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo" echo yoyo cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo"cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo" echo dudu"
cda=lolololo
```

i also tried `sed -i "s#${old}#${new}#g" ./sample.txt` but not difference.
can i get some help? thx very much

Comment: The `&` character has a special meaning in a sed replacement string. ["Escape a string for a sed replace pattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern/2705678#2705678) should explain what you need to do.

Comment: This also looks like a variation on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this - `sed` already knows exactly how to find the line which contains `cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
sed -E -i '' 's@(cmd="echo hihi && echo yoyo)"@\1 \&\& echo dudu"@' sample.txt
```

notice you have to escape the `&`.

Comment: sadly looks doesnt work...i tried and got a error `sed: -e expression #1, char 52: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`,  moreover,  `old` and `new` are dynamicly changed, so i need these expressions

Comment: my bad, see edit, `-i` is followed by an extension

Comment: glad to find a way works`sed -i "/^cmd=*/c$new" ./sample.txt`

Comment: The extension after `-i` is optional (at least in GNU sed).  If there is no extension,  no backup file is created (see the man-page for `sed`).

Comment: `sed [-Ealnu] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]` on macOS, not optional but can be empty to not create a backup file

Answer (score -1):

the key change should be:

```bash
sed -i "/^cmd=*/c$new" ./sample.txt
```

the full shell script is:

```bash
old=`cat ./sample.txt|grep cmd`
app=' && echo dudu"'

new=${old:0:-1}${app}

sed -i "/^cmd=*/c$new" ./sample.txt
```

Comment: What did you change and why does it help?

Comment: full script is as:
```sh
old=`cat ./sample.txt|grep cmd`;
app=' && echo dudu"';

new=${old:0:-1}${app};

# sed -i "s/${old}/${new}/g" ./sample.txt;
sed -i "/^cmd=*/c$new" ./sample.txt;
```

Comment: Please explain how this works.

Comment: @furynerd: Don't post multi-lines of statements in a comment. It's hard to read. If the information is relevant to your answer, edit the answer with it.