# apply sed only to the part of the file after last match in loop - shell / bash

Tags: bash, performance, shell, sed, large-files

I have a couple of large files (~1Gb) of such structure:

```
fooA iug9wa
fooA lauie
fooA nwgoieb
fooB wilgb
fooB rqgebepu
fooB ifbqeiu
...
fooN ibfiygb
fooN yvsiy
fooN aeviu
```

I would like to replace in shell each fooX (which contains letters, numbers "." and "_"), (I have all listed in `foo.list`) to sequential numbers 1 to N.

I've used:

```
nfoos=$(wc -l < foo.list)

for i in $(seq 1 $nfoos)
do
    currentfoo=$(sed "${i}q;d" foo.list)
    sed -i "s/"${currentfoo}"/$i/g" file1
    sed -i "s/"${currentfoo}"/$i/g" file2
    sed -i "s/"${currentfoo}"/$i/g" filen
done
```

However, with large files it's been taking forever.
Since each consecutive fooX always appears in the files than foo(X-1) I though to make `sed` only search the part of fileX after the last match of fooX, so that with each foo there is less space to search.
I've been trying to use labels and some multiline approaches, but the syntax keeps beating me here.

Does anyone know how to make it work? (Doesn't necessarily have to use `sed`, but would be great if it worked in basic shell in Bash.)

Appreciate any help. And if you do, please explain each function/option/variable used so that I can figure out where I had been messing up.

Comment: [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`.
The first part of the next `awk` command will fill the array a, the second part replaces the first word.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=NR; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]; print}' foo.list file1
```

When this is what you like, you can loop over your files

```
for f in file1 file2 filen; do
  awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=NR; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]; print}' foo.list "${f}" > "${f}.tmp" &&
  mv "${f}.tmp" "${f}"
done
```

The `&&` makes sure the new file will only replace the original file when `awk` was OK.

Comment: Glad I could help. Next time please add more example cases, such as a small `foo.list` and the result you want from the given input. Example input with dots and underscores might be releavant.

Comment: This solution removes lines from the inputfile that don't have a corresponding field in your foo.list. When you want to replace those lines with something like a `foo0`, create an if statemetn in the `awk`. Nice training!

Answer (score 0):

Two optimizations:

1. Use awk to generate a sed script which does all the replacements in a single run.
2. Run sed -i with N file arguments instead of running sed N times with 1 file argument each.

```bash
awk '{ print "s/" $0 "/" NR "/g;" }' foo.list > temp_script
sed -i -f temp_script $(cat foo.list)
```

Now you run sed only once instead of N^2 times.

Comment: OP write: `fooX contains letters, numbers "." and "_"`.
Values might be `val.`, `valx` and your `sed` command will match `val.` with `valx`.
You should replace the dows with `[.]` of `\.`.

Comment: I think you want to replace `sed -i -f temp_script $(cat foo.list)` with `sed -i -f temp_script file1 file 2 filen`.

Comment: Thanks @WalterA ! That is exactly the problem I ran into.
Replacing "_"'s kind of misses the whole point as I would have to replace them in the large files too and this would again, take a lot of time.
Reg. second comments, yes, I've noticed this too, but I got the point. I'll fix it in the reply.

Comment: You never need to have awk generate a sed script and then call sed to execute it, just do whatever you want to do in the one call to awk. What you show will fail for various input values, e.g. if `foo.list` contains `abc.e` then the sed command will replace `abcae`, `abc5e`, `abcXe`, etc.