# Any sed option to stop matching when one line number is reached?

Tags: bash, sed, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a table where only even rows are important (bold ones),

| year | month | day | time | lat | lon | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2020** | **1** | **1** | **00:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **272.4456** |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 00:00:00 | 47.97 | 21.68 | -32767 |
| **2020** | **1** | **1** | **01:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **272.3355** |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 01:00:00 | 47.97 | 21.68 | -32767 |
| **2020** | **1** | **1** | **02:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **272.1232** |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 02:00:00 | 47.97 | 21.68 | -32767 |
| 2020 | **1** | **1** | **03:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **271.8801** |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 03:00:00 | 47.97 | 21.68 | -32767 |

but, at some point, this changes to odd rows. This is the exact moment where it changes (you can see two consecutive "-32767"):

| year | month | day | time | lat | lon | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2023** | **9** | **30** | **23:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **289.2723** |
| 2023 | 9 | 30 | 23:00:00 | 41.97 | 29.68 | -32767 |
| 2023 | 10 | 1 | 00:00:00 | 41.97 | 29.68 | -32767 |
| **2023** | **10** | **1** | **00:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **288.9512** |
| 2023 | 10 | 1 | 01:00:00 | 41.97 | 29.68 | -32767 |
| **2023** | **10** | **1** | **01:00:00** | **41.97** | **29.68** | **288.7689** |
| 2023 | 10 | 1 | 02:00:00 | 41.97 | 29.68 | -32767 |

I found this out after extracting them with `sed '1~2d' site8_slt.nc.tsv`. Does anyone know how to sed until a specific line number? This way I would sed two times, first before the change and then after the change.

Thanks in advance!

*Context:* I am downloading data from cds.climate.copernicus.eu in netCDF format and then converting the data to csv with cdo (Climate Data Operators), and, I dont know why, I get 2 values per row where each value is always the fill value -32767.

*I have tried*: I know that I can point to specific lines with this `$ sed '1s/a/b/' file` but this only changes one line, I want to to sed all lines before one in a way, and then sed in another way after one specific line number.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using sed?  Awk is usually better for tabular data.  In any case, with GNU sed, you can use a step addressing within a block addressed by a range: `0,/-32767$/{`, `1~2s/a/b/`, `}`.

Comment: You might simply want to ignore lines ending in the fill value:  `/-32767$/!s/a/b/`.

Comment: I'd be inclined to go back a step and try to work out why (presumably correct) original data is being converted into something broken. If this is broken, how do you know nothing else is wrong too?

Comment: Perhaps see also [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)

Comment: @Tankibor: Are the comments or answer helping you?

Comment: Yes @WalterA thank you all. Both Toby answers are ok. And regarding jhnc question, I have tested downloading a small proportion of data on the web server of ERA5 and althought I don't get the -32767 rows, the other rows have the same values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n '1,3p'
1
2
3

$ seq 5 | sed -n '4,$p'
4
5
```

but it sounds like either of these might be more useful for you, using any sed or any awk:

```
sed '/-32767$/d' file
awk '$NF != -32767' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
year    month   day     time    lat     lon     value
2020    1       1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.4456
2020    1       1       00:00:00        47.97   21.68   -32767
2020    1       1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.3355
2020    1       1       01:00:00        47.97   21.68   -32767
2020    1       1       02:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.1232
2020    1       1       02:00:00        47.97   21.68   -32767
2020    1       1       03:00:00        41.97   29.68   271.8801
2020    1       1       03:00:00        47.97   21.68   -32767
2023    9       30      23:00:00        41.97   29.68   289.2723
2023    9       30      23:00:00        41.97   29.68   -32767
2023    10      1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   -32767
2023    10      1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   288.9512
2023    10      1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   -32767
2023    10      1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   288.7689
2023    10      1       02:00:00        41.97   29.68   -32767
```

```
$ sed '/-32767$/d' file
year    month   day     time    lat     lon     value
2020    1       1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.4456
2020    1       1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.3355
2020    1       1       02:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.1232
2020    1       1       03:00:00        41.97   29.68   271.8801
2023    9       30      23:00:00        41.97   29.68   289.2723
2023    10      1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   288.9512
2023    10      1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   288.7689
```

```
$ awk '$NF != -32767' file
year    month   day     time    lat     lon     value
2020    1       1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.4456
2020    1       1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.3355
2020    1       1       02:00:00        41.97   29.68   272.1232
2020    1       1       03:00:00        41.97   29.68   271.8801
2023    9       30      23:00:00        41.97   29.68   289.2723
2023    10      1       00:00:00        41.97   29.68   288.9512
2023    10      1       01:00:00        41.97   29.68   288.7689
```

`awk` will almost certainly be much more useful to you than `sed` in doing whatever else you want to do with this data.