# replace pattern in lines with data find in another file with sed in BASH

Tags: sed, replace, capturing-group

I have 2 files: a channellist file and a global source file containing data of all channels.

In the channellist there are f.i. these 2 lines; of course there are a lot more and all lines are starting with #SERVICE 1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::

```
#SERVICE 1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::Channel 4#DESCRIPTION channel 4"
#SERVICE 1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::Sky History#DESCRIPTION sky history"
```

In the global source file is f.i. somewhere:

```
28.2e channel4.uk 1:0:1:2085:808:2:11A0000:0:0:0: channel 4 
28.2e skyhistory.uk 1:0:1:C4C0:811:2:11A0000:0:0:0: sky history
```

What I want is in the channellist file the ‘old’ service reference 1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0: be replaced (IN PLACE: sed -i) by the corresponing one from the global source file (found by making use of the channel name). As an example here, as you can see, the 2 'new' service references from the global source file are:

```
1:0:1:2085:808:2:11A0000:0:0:0:  (=Channel 4 )
1:0:1:C4C0:811:2:11A0000:0:0:0: (=Sky History)
```

So actually I want to replace in the channellist file '1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:' by '1:0:1:2085:808:2:11A0000:0:0:0:' for channel 4 and by ''1:0:1:C4C0:811:2:11A0000:0:0:0:' for Sky History.

What should be done for the line with channel 4 is f.i.:

1. grab the channel name in the channellist file (which is f.i. behind ‘#DESCRIPTION’ at a line;
2. find the line in the global source file with that channel name (all channel names are everywhere already converted to lowercase);
3. get from that line (in the global source file) the ‘new’ service reference which is in a line after the 2nd space and before the 3rd space;
4. replace in the channellist the old service reference (1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:) with the new one (1:0:1:2085:808:2:11A0000:0:0:0:).

Maybe it is the wrong direction, but since I do not know if 'sed group capturing' is needed for the solution, I know 'manually' how to change the service reference by making use of sed group capturing, but without looking up. So how to find (lookup) the data in the global source file by making use of the channel name which is actually in captured group 4 (see below).

SED group capturing channellist file:

1. capture group 1: from the beginning to #SERVICE [space] => (.*#SERVICE )
2. capture group 2: from 1, capture everything till :: (which is in fact the service reference which must be replaced) => (.*::)
3. capture group 3: from 2, caputure everything till #DESCRIPTION [space] => (.#DESCRIPTION )
4. capture group 4: from 3, capture everything till the end (which is in fact the channel name) => (.*)

As a test just here, I did make use (just for now) of the variables oldLine (which is a line in the channellist file) and newSREF:

```
oldLine="#SERVICE 1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::Channel 4#DESCRIPTION channel 4".
newSREF="1:0:1:2085:808:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
```

The command is:

```
sed "s/\(.*#SERVICE \)\(.*::\)\(.*#DESCRIPTION \)\(.*\)/\1${newSREF}\3\4/g" <<< $oldLine
```

Comment: I think your `sed` command is wrong when you want to REPLACE the old service ref. Remove the `\2` like `sed "s/\(.*#SERVICE \)\(.*::\)\(.*#DESCRIPTION \)\(.*\)/\1${newSREF}\3\4/g" <<< $oldLine`.

Comment: Yes, sorry slip of my pen; will edit it. But that didn't answer my question

Comment: Finding the `${newSREF}` in a loop will create a terrible, slow loop. First, you need to parse the global file and create some kind of array with `a[description]=serviceref`. Next, use the array for the replacements. `sed` without repeating system calls will be hard, you might use something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877/3220113. First create the lookup array with the global file, next start match/replace.

Comment: When you really want to use `sed` and you know that the DESCRIPTIONs don't have special (in view of  `sed`) characters like `&` and `/`, you might want to parse the global file first creating a sed command file (with lines like `s/\(.*#SERVICE \)\(.*::\)\(.*#DESCRIPTION \)\(.*\)/\11:0:1:2085:808:2:11A0000:0:0:0:\3\4/`) and next start `sed` on the second file: `sed -f <(sed something globalfile) channellist`. The solution with `awk` is better (no nasty special cases to solve).

Comment: *"Here ... the 2 'new' service references from the global source file are...."* .. where did the parens and `=` come from in `(=Channel 4 )` in your sample output? Do you really want those extra characters included? I also notice that, if you used an `awk` model for you data, and used the `:` char as the FieldSeparator value, your inputs have 12 fields, while the output has only 11 fields. This would be relatively easy to create your output with `awk` using an array of the "new" values and match on the `$NF` (last field) in the line, overwriting the $4-$7 fileds from the "new" array. GoodLuck

Comment: Perhaps see also [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this); the main question is tangential but there is also a discussion of `sed` in a loop in the answer.

Comment: Do you REALLY have unmatched double quotes at the end of each line in channellist? If not, please [edit] your question to fix that.

Comment: Regarding `IN PLACE: sed -i` - updating the input file or any other file is trivial and shouldn't be part of any question as it just introduces clutter and irrelevant details, making it harder to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Walter A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220113/walter-a) for his excellent suggestion(s). I visited the link he posted in his 1st reaction here and there (in the 1st reaction/answer) I found [idiomatic awk](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk): i.e. under ‘Two-file processing’ to change the opcodes in the file data.txt by making use of the file map.txt with the command (there): awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$3=a[$3]}1' map.txt data.txt

1. First I  used awk to convert in both files (globlal soure file and channellist file) the channelnames to lowercase.
2. Then I reduced the global source file into 2 columns: service reference (column 1) and channelname (column 2); more data is not needed.
3. In the channellist file I added a space at the end of the service reference and before the channel name (so after the 2 colons) to create an extra column for the service reference; which will be used later for easy replacement.
4. Because a channelname can consist of multiple words and thus multiple columns: I changed in both files (by using awk) the space (if available0 in the columns 2,3,4,5 etc  to 2 underscores (‘__’); so the channelnames are now in 1 column. This will be changed back later of course.
5. Because I am using an old version of awk (option '-i inplace' is not available) I copied the ‘channellist file’ to ‘channellist file_tmp’ (as temporary file)

Now I was ready to take the channelnames (2nd column in the global source file) and use the corresponding service rerence (1st column), then lookup the same channelname in the channellist file and replace the ‘old’ service reference with the one from the global source file with the command:

`awk 'NR == FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} {$2=a[$3]}1' [global source file] [channellist file]_tmp] > [channellist file]`

Comment: Nice to see you solved the problem. You can accept your own answer, so everybody sees that the problem is solved.