# Reading and writing in Shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to do a very basic operation in Shell. I have the following file:

```
id DiaMatch(32) = Sector(C26, 9, 1021) * Shift(k2, k2-p1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k1, []);
id DiaMatch(33) = Sector(C26, 9, 1021) * Shift(k2, k2-p1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k1, []);
id DiaMatch(34) = Sector(C10, 9, 1022) * Shift(k2, -p1+k1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k2, []);
id DiaMatch(35) = Sector(C10, 9, 1022) * Shift(k2, -p1+k1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k2, []);
```

and so on.

I have to extract from this file to a new file with the following:

```
file C26;
replace_(k2, k2-p1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k1);
end;

file C26;
replace_(k2, k2-p1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k1);
end;

file C10;
replace_(k2, -p1+k1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k2);
end;
```

and so on

I am trying to do this operation line by line as

```
while read line; do
    sed -n '/shift/{s/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/;s/\[//g;s/\]//g;p}'
    echo $line
done < qqbz.match.info.inc
```

but this is not working. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this) tangentially discusses running `sed` in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell is for launching commands, you could but shouldn't use it for anything much more complicated than that. Awk is not shell, you could use for example it. I left some for exercise (add `%s`s and `$n`s in the `printf`):

```
$ awk -F"[()]" '{
     split($4,a,/, /)
     split($6,b,/, /)
     printf "file %s;\nreplace(%s, %s, ...);\nend;\n\n",a[1],b[1],b[2]
}' file
```

Output:

```
file C26;
replace(k2, k2-p1, ...);
end;

file C26;
replace(k2, k2-p1, ...);
end;

file C10;
replace(k2, -p1+k1, ...);
end;

file C10;
replace(k2, -p1+k1, ...);
end;
```

Comment: I assume you got the idea?

Comment: thanks. How to store in a file?

Comment: `awk ... file > newfile` If  you run it as a one-liner, add `; ` between each command: `split(...);split(...);printf ...` Sorry, can't stay longer, must run. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

the `regex`-only approach without using `split()` or `printf()` :

```
echo '

id DiaMatch(32) = Sector(C26, 9, 1021) * Shift(k2, k2-p1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k1, []);
id DiaMatch(33) = Sector(C26, 9, 1021) * Shift(k2, k2-p1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k1, []);
id DiaMatch(34) = Sector(C10, 9, 1022) * Shift(k2, -p1+k1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k2, []);
id DiaMatch(35) = Sector(C10, 9, 1022) * Shift(k2, -p1+k1, [], k3, -k3, [], k1, p1-k2, []);' |
```

---

```
mawk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = RS (ORS = ""); RS = "^$" } 
  gsub(/(^|\n)[^=]+=[^(]+[(]/,         "file ") + \
  gsub(/,[^][*]+[*] Shift[(]/,  ";\nreplace_(") + \
  gsub(/[)][;]/,  "&\nend;\n\n") + gsub(/, +[[][]]/,_)^_'
```

---

```
 1  file C26;
 2  replace_(k2, k2-p1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k1);
 3  end;

 4  file C26;
 5  replace_(k2, k2-p1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k1);
 6  end;

 7  file C10;
 8  replace_(k2, -p1+k1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k2);
 9  end;

10  file C10;
11  replace_(k2, -p1+k1, k3, -k3, k1, p1-k2);
12  end;
```

Comment: "without using split() or printf()".  You **forgot** to explain why this needs `mawk`, in stead of `awk`. Does is really **need** mawk, or is there something which you did not tell here?

Comment: @Luuk : any `awk` works i was just pasting in the command i tested and `awk` is hard-linked to `nawk` on my system, and i try avoiding `nawk` at all costs

Comment: `nawk` or `mawk` , see: [awk, mawk, nawk, gawk... WHAT?](https://superuser.com/questions/75875/awk-mawk-nawk-gawk-what)

Comment: @Luuk : which part of `nawk` was confusing you ? the N, the A, the W, or the K ?

Comment: @Luuk : `nawk` is ultra easy to identify : `index("", "") == 0`. And ps : whoever the author of that link you attached is beyond brain dead. `nawk` is such a bad `awk` it's only barely above the steaming pile that is `Solaris` `awk`.