# Question about the input variable of sed in shell

Tags: shell

I want to identify the obsolete configuration items in etcsshsshd_config and use the sed command to delete the obsolete configuration items.

```
line=$(sshd -t 2>&1 | awk '{print $NF}'); for config in $line; do sed -i "/$config/d" /etc/ssh/sshd_config; done
```

But this command doesn't work. Why?

I tried adding braces and double quotes to the variable, but it didn't work

The value of $line is:

```
RSAAuthentication
RhostsRSAAuthentication
```

Comment: What is the value of `$line`?

Comment: (Probably not the issue, but a more stable way to do this than a fragile `for ... in $var` would be `sshd -t 2>&1 | awk '{print $NF}' | while read -r config ; do ...`.)

Comment: I use ```sshd -t 2>&1 | awk '{print $NF}' | while read -r line; do  sed -i "/$line/d" /etc/ssh/sshd_config; done```,but it not work

Comment: If you run `sshd -t 2>&1 | awk '{print $NF}' | while read -r line; do ( set -x ; sed -i "/$line/d" /etc/ssh/sshd_config ) done` you should see what the `sed` commands look like. What do you see?

Comment: ```+ sed -i $'/RSAAuthentication\r/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config```

Comment: Ah, the dreaded `\r`! See @tripleee’s answer.

Comment: thanks!I learned to print variables using the set -x method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separately, running `sed -i` in a loop is something you want to avoid. See [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)

Without access to the output of `sshd -t` or the file you want to modify, it's impossible to debug your problem. But perhaps try this instead.

```
sshd -t 2>&1 |
sed 's%.* /%;s%$%/d' |
sed -i -f - /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If your `sshd` output could contain tabs as well as spaces, or the tokens could contain slashes, adapt accordingly.

... Or, if the output from `sshd` could contain invisible DOS cartiage returns, that would explain your problem. Try throwing in a `tr -d '\015'` before the first `sed` (or, in your Awk scipt, `sub(/\r/, "");`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings for more on DOS carriage return characters.

Comment: Solved the problem perfectly, thanks

Comment: So did you have a stray CR in there?

Comment: yes,I saw this using the set -x method