# Substitute pattern by an other pattern from two lists using while read line and sed

Tags: awk, sed, while-loop, fasta

I try to replace in several files some patterns by other patterns. For example my infile looks like this:

```
>Genus_species_SRR13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGCTGGGCCTGCGAGACACCAGCACCCCCATCGTGGCCATCACCCTGCACAGCCTCGCCGTGCTGGTCTCCCTGCTCGGACCAGAGGTGGTTGTGGGCGGAGAAAGAACCAAGATCTTCAAACGCACTGCCCCCAGCTTTACAAAAACCACTGACCTCTCCCCAGAAGAC
```

and I want output:

```
>Genus_species_Something_something|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGCTGGGCCTGCGAGACACCAGCACCCCCATCGTGGCCATCACCCTGCACAGCCTCGCCGTGCTGGTCTCCCTGCTCGGACCAGAGGTGGTTGTGGGCGGAGAAAGAACCAAGATCTTCAAACGCACTGCCCCCAGCTTTACAAAAACCACTGACCTCTCCCCAGAAGAC
```

I have two list files, my old patterns:

```
Genus_species_SRR13259292
```

and new patterns:

```
Genus_species_Something_something
```

I tried to do this with `sed`. Here is my command:

```
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2 <&3; do
    for f in *.fasta; do
        sed -e "s/${line1}/${line2}/g" "$f" > "${f%.fasta}_NewName.fasta"
    done
done < "List_oldpattern.txt" 3<"List_newpatterns.txt"
```

But this doesn't work, maybe it is because of the `>` and `|` delimited the pattern?

If `sed` doesn't work it may be possible with Awk?

Comment: Assuming more than one old/new pattern pair to replace, I see one issue with the current code; for discussion puposes assume 2 old/new patterns and one `*.fasta` file; first pass through the `while` loop the first old/new pattern will be replaced and the output file will be created; on the 2nd pass through the `while` loop the second old/new pattern will be replaced (from the original source file - does not include the previous old/new replacement) and the output file will overwrite the previous output file; net result: final ouput file will only contain the last old/new replacement

Comment: It's generally preferable to use bioinformatics software for this type of task, instead of custom awk, perl, python, etc scripts, as you can run into trouble with 'edge cases'. One potential option is to use [seqkit 'replace'](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#replace). Example 8 appears very similar to your problem. Good luck!

Comment: [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this) has a discussion of your approach near the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question has been tagged with `awk` I propose we replace all of OP's current code with a single `awk` script ...

My sample `.fasta` files:

```
$ head f?.fasta
==> f1.fasta <==
>Genus_species_SRR13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772           # change
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....

>Genus_buckets_ABC13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772           # do not change
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....

==> f2.fasta <==
>Genus_species_SRR13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772           # change
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....

>Genus_buckets_ABC13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772           # do not change
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....
```

**NOTE:** files do not contain the comments

We'll make use of the `paste` command to append OP's old and new patterns into a single line; we'll use a `|` as the delimiter:

```
$ paste -d'|' List_oldpattern.txt List_newpatterns.txt
Genus_species_SRR13259292|Genus_species_Something_something
```

Now the `awk` script:

```
awk '
BEGIN     { FS = OFS = "|" }                    # input/output field delimiter
FNR==NR   { map[">" $1] = ">" $2; next }        # 1st file (paste output): populate our map[] array; $1==old $2==new; then skip to next input line
FNR==1    { close(outf)                         # 2nd-nth files: 1st record; close previous output file
            outf = FILENAME                     # make copy of input FILENAME
            sub(/\.fasta$/,"",outf)             # strip trailing ".fasta"
            outf = outf "_NewName.fasta"        # append new suffix to our output filename
          }
$1 in map { $1 = map[$1] }                      # if 1st field (">some_string") is an index in the map[] array then replace 1st field with array contents
          { print > outf }                      # print current line to output file

' <(paste -d'|' List_oldpattern.txt List_newpatterns.txt) *.fasta
```

**NOTE:** assuming OP has more than one old/new pattern pair, this script has the added benefit of only scanning each `*.fasta` file once (as opposed to OP's current `while/read/for/sed` loop which scans each `.fasta` file `N` times - where `N` is the number of old/new pattern pairs)

This generates:

```
$ head *_NewName.fasta
==> f1_NewName.fasta <==
>Genus_species_Something_something|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772   # changed
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....

>Genus_buckets_ABC13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772           # not changed
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....

==> f2_NewName.fasta <==
>Genus_species_Something_something|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772   # changed
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....

>Genus_buckets_ABC13259292|ENSG00000000457_ENST00000367772           # not changed
TACGCCGCGCACTTCACGCGAGAGCAGCTGCGCACTATCGTCCTGCCCCAGGTGCTGC....
```

Comment: `sub(/\.fasta$/,"_NewName&",outf)` ?

Comment: Hello,
thank you very much! The command work well, and I am surprised it run quickly despite the large number of file and pattern I have to change.

Comment: @Nico64 a good bit of the speed up is associated with the fact that this script only scans each fasta file once (vs your current script that has to scan each fasta file N times, where N == number of old/new pairs to be processed); another boost in performance comes from calling `awk` once vs calling `sed` MxN times (M == number of fasta files)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' '
    FNR==1 { n++ }
    n==1 {    f[FNR]   = ">"$0; next }
    n==2 { t[ f[FNR] ] = ">"$0; next }

    { print $1 in t ? t[$1] substr($0,length($1)+1) : $0 }
' fromlist tolist fastafile
```

- store from strings from first file
- create from→to map from corresponding line of second file
- split fasta lines on `|`
- if first field is in the map, convert it, else print as-is

Comment: was going to make it handle multiple fasta but I see markp-fuso already shows how to do that

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i.bak -E '1{x;s/.*/paste fileOld fileNew/e;x};G
               s/^>([^|]+)([^\n]+).*\n\1\t([^\n]+)/>\3\2/;P;d' file ...
```

This solution makes a copy of the pasted old and new files in the hold space and then appends this copy to each line and uses pattern matching to subtitute old for new.

The files are replaced by the `-i` option and backups are made of each file with the extention `.bak`.